# Test ignored and failing when running IT test in Spring Boot (MongoDB Test Container)

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, maven, integration-testing, testcontainers

I am trying to run an IT test using a MongoDB test container. However, I get the following error when I run the test

***com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.InternalServerErrorException: Status 500: {"message":"Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/testcontainers/ryuk/manifests/0.3.1": unauthorized: incorrect username or password"}
at org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.DefaultInvocationBuilder.execute(DefaultInvocationBuilder.java:247)
at org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.DefaultInvocationBuilder.lambda$executeAndStream$1(DefaultInvocationBuilder.java:269)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)***

Here is the IT Test:

```
@Testcontainers
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ProductIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    // Step 1 - Download mongodb test container
    @Container
    static MongoDBContainer mongoDBContainer = new MongoDBContainer("mongo:4.0.10");

    // Step 2 - Add ReplicaSetUrl dynamically (We don't want to connect to real DB, but the test container)
    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void setProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry dynamicPropertyRegistry) {
        dynamicPropertyRegistry.add("spring.data.mongodb.uri", mongoDBContainer::getReplicaSetUrl);
    }

    @Test
    void shouldCreateProduct() throws Exception {
        ProductRequest productRequest = getProductRequest();
        String productRequestString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(productRequest);
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/api/product")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(productRequestString))
                .andExpect(status().isCreated());
        Assertions.assertEquals(1, productRepository.findAll().size());
    }

    private ProductRequest getProductRequest() {
        return ProductRequest.builder()
                .name("iPhone 13")
                .description("iPhone 13")
                .price(BigDecimal.valueOf(1200))
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like `https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/testcontainers/ryuk/manifests/0.3.1": unauthorized: incorrect username or password` you don't have correct permissions..

Comment: I didn't think I would need to sign in to use a test container?

Comment: The error message states different...You have to provide the credentials to use docker images from the appropriate registry...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You did likely run into this issue:
https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/5121

As a workaround, login to Docker Hub using this URL:

```
docker login index.docker.io
```

Comment: This worked. Image pulled successfully. Thank you!

Comment: I just logged out of Docker Desktop, restarted Docker and it worked. As @KevinWittek mentions the issue link, you will find this a 2nd approach in that ticket. I then updated my testcontainers to version 18.3 for dockerDesktop v4.22.0 and the issue is gone.